# Losing data rows when uploading to Excel sheet using office.js

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have a variable `values` with 174 rows, but when I upload it into an Excel sheet with the following office.js code, the sheet only has 24 rows. Why is that?

```
function load_data(histo) {

    var values = []; 

    for (var i = 0; i < histo.length; i++) {
        var temp = [];
        var d = histo[i].split("~");
        for (var j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
            temp.push(d[j]);
        }
        values.push(temp);
    } 

    // Run a batch operation against the Excel object model
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {

        // Create a proxy object for the active sheet
        var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();         
        sheet.getRange("A1:V174").values = values; 
        // Run the queued-up commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion
        return ctx.sync();
    })
        .catch(errorHandler);


}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce with very small histo array ["bob~sally", "tom~vishwa"] (and range A1:B2). Could you do some experiments and see if data size has an effect? Can we see how you are calling the method? Also, you don't seem to have a try block to correspond to your catch block.

Comment: I can't reproduce even with full size data.

Comment: @MKT, it's difficult for others to troubleshoot this issue without being able to reproduce it themselves.  I'd suggest that you consider using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab), a free Office Add-in, to create a snippet that reproduces your error. Then, you can use Script Lab to quickly/easily publish your snippet to a public Gist and post the id here, and we can try to reproduce and troubleshoot your code ourselves by using Script Lab.   Just a suggestion, if you're up for trying it.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was able to run @MKT 's code (after commenting out the catch block). What I meant by saying that I can't reproduce is that the code works without error for me. I get all 174 rows and 24 columns.

Comment: @RickKirkham are you using the same code? or have you made changes??

Comment: @RickKirkham thank you for the suggestion, I ll follow that.

Comment: @MKT Same code except for commenting out the catch line.

Comment: Its working, there is some problem in that data file, I am able to upload other data files. thank you guys